# Can a granddaughter claim her grandfather's property after both her father and grandfather have died according to Muslim law?

Tags: india, inheritance, indian-constitutional-law

F had three sons: A, B and C.

A died.  20 years later F died, followed by the death of A's wife leaving a surviving daughter.

Following the death of F, his property transferred to the two surviving sons: B and C.

Does A's daughter have any legal basis of claim to F's property?

Also, unbeknownst to A's daughter,  many years ago her father's property was sold by her uncles B and C. According to the Karnataka, India Muslim law she can hire an advocate to lodge a claim on her grandfather's property and her father's property that was sold. Is this correct?

Comment: I suspect that English is not your native language and don't wish to offend. But it is hard to follow the facts in the question. The last sentence is particularly hard to understand. The order of death is also unclear. Maybe a timeline would help?

Comment: Why question is unclear, okay I will explain another way Question: F have three sons A, B and C, first 'A ' son got expired and A have one doughter also after years F (father) expired and In this case A doughter can claim. @ohwilleke